# How to document a nested function within a method in JSdoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

In javascript I have a method which has a function inside of it, when trying to document It with the program JSdocs I assumed that It would **have to look like this:**

```
 /**
  * @memberof dataBase#query
  * @inner
  * @function makeArray
  * @description ..
*/
```

**or like this:**

```
/**
  * @function dataBase#query~makeArray
  * @description ..
*/
```

But for some reason it does not show up.

**Question:** Is there any way for me to document this kind of function?

EDIT:

You may notice some places in my code below where on line continues on to the next line, this is simply because of the limited space provided by the stackoverflow question box and is not part of my source code.

Here is the code I want to document (specifically the makeArray function inside of the query method):

```
exports.dataBase = class dataBase {
  constructor(connection, X64) {
    this.connectString = connection
    this.X64 = X64
    this.connection = adodb.open(connection, X64)
    this._this = this
    this.shortcuts = require('./shortcuts')
  }

  async close() {
    await this.connection.close()
    return
  }

  async reopen() {
    this.connection = adodb.open(this.connectString, this.X64)
    return
  }

  async shortcut(type, data) {
    await this.shortcuts.data[type](data, this._this)
    return 
  }

  async runSQL(sql) {
    let type
    if(sql.match('SELECT')) {
      type = 'query'
    } else {
      type = 'execute'
    }
    let data
    let self = this
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      self.connection[type](sql).then(result => {
        data = result
        resolve()
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
    return data
  }

  async query(table, columns = '*' || [], rows = '*' || [], options = '*'             
|| []) {
    function makeArray(str) {
      if(typeof str === 'string' && str !== '*') {
        return [str]
      }
    }

    makeArray(columns)
    makeArray(rows)
    makeArray(options)

    function processData(table, columns, rows, options) {
      function processColumns(columns) {
        let retval = ''
        for(let i in columns) {
          if(i != columns.length - 1) {
            retval += `${columns[i]},`
          } else {
            retval += `${columns[i]}`
            return retval
          }
        }

      }

      function processRows(rows) {
        let retval = ''
        for(let i in rows) {
          if(i != rows.length - 1) {
            retval += `ID=${rows[i]} AND `
          } else {
            retval += `ID=${rows[i]}`
          }
        }
        return retval
      }

      function processOptions(options) {
        let retval = ''
        for(let i in rows) {
            retval += ` AND ${options[i]}`
        }
        return retval
      }

      let SQLcolumns = processColumns(columns)
      let SQLrows = processRows(rows)
      let SQLoptions = processOptions(options)

      if(rows === '*' && options === '*') {
        return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}];`
      } else if(options === '*') {
        return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}] WHERE ${SQLrows};`
      } else if(rows === '*') {
        return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}] WHERE ${SQLoptions};`
      } else {
        return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}] WHERE     
 ${SQLrows}${SQLoptions};`
      }
    }

    let data
    await this.runSQL(processData(table, columns, rows,     
options)).then((result) => {
      data = result
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
    return data
  }

  async createTable(name, columns, rows = null) {
    function processColumns(columns) {
      let retval = ''
      for(let i of Object.keys(columns)) {
        if(i !== Object.keys(columns)[columns.size() - 1]) {
          retval += `${i} ${columns[i]},\n`
        } else {
          retval += `${i} ${columns[i]}`
        }
      }
      return retval
    }
    let data
    let SQLcolumns = processColumns(columns)

    await this.runSQL(`CREATE TABLE ${name}     
(\n${SQLcolumns}\n);`).then((result) => {
      data = result
    })  

    if(rows !== null) {
      this.addRecords(name, rows)
    }
  }

  async addRecords(table, values) {
    let data = []
    function processValues(values) {
      let retval = ''
      for(let i of Object.keys(values)) {
        if(i !== Object.keys(values)[values.size() - 1]) {
          retval += `${values[i]}, `
        } else {
          retval += values[i]
        }
      }
      return retval
    }

    for(let i of values) {
      let SQLvalues
      SQLvalues = processValues(i)
      await this.runSQL(`INSERT INTO [${table}] VALUES 
(${SQLvalues});`).then((result) => {
        data.push(result)
      })
    }

    return data
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not the proper use for `@inner` if I understand what you are asking. Can you provide the code you are trying to document?

Comment: @chazsolo I have added my source code now.

Comment: What's your purpose? Do you want the `makeArray` function to appear in your JSDoc-generated documentation, and if so, how? `makeArray` is private and inaccessible outside of the `query` method, and *in general* such functions don't need to (and arguably should not) appear in your class' documentation.

Comment: Local functions are not public API and are not included in JSdoc. Use a normal comment..?

Comment: This is being documented for a teacher, so I want the documentation to be very extensive. If I were to be documenting this for  a library then I would agree that the extra documentation would be unnecessary.