# Why do some functions show up in JSDoc and others don't?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

This function shows up in the html file.

```
/**
 * This function allows us to display a graph depending on the selection in a dropdown list
 * @param {object} object the div that is passed into the function
 */
/**
 * This function allows us to display a graph depending on the selection in a dropdown list
 * @param {object} object the div that is passed into the function
 */
function changeTitle(object) {
  /**
   * This retrieves the option clicked within the dropdown.
   */
  const dropdownChoice = document.getElementById('gdropdown').selectedIndex;
  /**
   * This collects the carousel meant to show if the heel height/UK economy line graph is selected.
   */
  const carousel = document.getElementById('yearscarousel');
  /**
   * This selects the caption that should be displayed alongside the carousel.
   */
  const carouselCaption = document.getElementById('linecaption');
  carousel.style.display = 'none';
  carouselCaption.style.display = 'none';
  if (dropdownChoice === 0) {
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'Scatter Graph that shows the skin colour of Vogue cover models';
    document.getElementById('scatgraph').innerHTML = '';
    /**
     * set the dimensions and margins of the graph
     */
    var margin = {
      top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60,
    };
    var width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    /**
     *  append the svg object to the body of the page
     */
    var svg = d3.select('#scatgraph')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`,
      );

    // Read the data
    d3.csv('faces.csv', (data) => {
      /**
       *  this creates the x axis of the scatter graph
       */
      const x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date('01-01-2000'), new Date('01-01-2020')])
        .range([0, 500]);
      svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      /**
       * This adds the y axis of the scatter graph.
       */
      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([height, 0]);
      svg.append('g')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      /**
       * Add a tooltip div. Here I define the general feature of the tooltip: stuff that do not depend on the data point.
       * Its opacity is set to 0: we don't see it by default.
       */
      const tooltip = d3.select('#scatgraph')
        .append('div')
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .attr('class', 'tooltip')
        .style('background-color', 'white')
        .style('border', 'solid')
        .style('border-width', '1px')
        .style('border-radius', '5px')

        .style('padding', '10px')
        .style('width', '20%');

      /**
       *
       * @param {Object} d
       */
      const mouseover = function (d) {
        tooltip
          .style('opacity', 1);
        console.log('Successful');
      };
      /**
       *
       * @param {Object} d
       */
      const mousemove = function (d) {
        tooltip
          .html(`Model name: ${d.model}`)
          .style('color', d.tone)
          .style('padding', '10px')
          .style('position', 'fixed')
          .style('left', `${d3.mouse(this)[0] + 50}px`) // It is important to put the +90: other wise the tooltip is exactly where the point is an it creates a weird effect
          .style('top', `${d3.mouse(this)[1]}px`);
        console.log('Successful');
      };

      /**
       * A function that change this tooltip when the leaves a point: just need to set opacity to 0 again
       * @param {Object} d
       */
      const mouseleave = function (d) {
        tooltip
          .transition()
          .duration(400)
          .style('opacity', 0);
        console.log('Succsessful');
      };

      // Add dots
      svg.append('g')
        .selectAll('dot')
        .data(data.filter((d, i) => i < 50)) // the .filter part is just to keep a few dots on the chart, not all of them
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', (d) => x(new Date(d.date)))
        .attr('cy', (d) => y(d.l))
        .attr('r', 7)
        .style('fill', '#c2044a')
        .style('opacity', 0.3)
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .on('mouseover', mouseover)

        .on('mousemove', mousemove)
        .on('mouseleave', mouseleave);

      svg.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'x label')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('x', width - 20)
        .attr('y', height)
        .text('Year');

      svg.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'y label')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.75em')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .text('L Value for Skin Tone');

      console.log('Successful');
    });
  }
}
```

The code directly below is in the middle of the two functions.

```
console.log('The graphs should be working');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
```

But this function doesn't show up,

```
/**
 * This function creates an alert box and resets value of the form
 * @param {event} click when the submit button is pressed
 */
function clickHandler(event) {
  alert('Thanks for your wonderful input.');
  document.getElementById('sleekform').reset();
  document.getElementById('sleektexta').value = '';
}
document.getElementById('submitB').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

I run the jsdoc using
'npm install -g jsdoc'
then
'jsdoc sleekscript.js'
in a terminal.

GARbkefhoijf4rpg4r
g3r hoig43jofrosjlfdvjks; kfpojfspokrposjojrtsihsd
ierherjseikfs
rwrwrrjvw;ihwihrw#fvwbwfo
kjbvefjrjoerjuervbevbdv

Comment: The `addEventListener()` is calling an existing function , not defining a new  one.

Comment: the second thing isn't a fucntion... what exactly do you think should show up?

Comment: So JSDoc is only used for functions that you define and not preexisting ones and/or ones from libraries.

Comment: You've added a significant amount of code. Please may you cut it down and keep only what is relevant? (Or do some debugging) It could be a spelling mistake, or a syntax error, which is preventing jsdoc from showing the function.

Comment: Also, the first function has two comments? I assume this is a mistake.

Comment: I cut the code down to only include the first if statement as the second is just the first repeated with minor changes.

Comment: The function had a typo but there is only one comment in my actual js file.

Comment: Quick tip: try not to define functions inside if/else blocks.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer

In response to the question update:

> Local functions are not public API and are not included in JSdoc.

From [How to document a nested function within a method in JSdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775705/how-to-document-a-nested-function-within-a-method-in-jsdoc)

Define these functions outside the if/else blocks and the function, and then JSDoc will see them.

*(This is why questions should always include a true [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the start)*

---

### Original Answer

To document the function being passed to the event listener, define it first and then pass it in.

```js
/**
 * This function creates an alert box and resets value of the form
 * @param {event} click when the submit button is pressed
 */
const clickHandler = (event) => {
  alert('Thanks for your wonderful input.');
  document.getElementById('sleekform').reset();
  document.getElementById('sleektexta').value = '';
};

document.getElementById('submitB').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

> JSDoc's purpose is to document the API of *your* JavaScript application or library
> (emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for this, but when refreshing the JSDoc file this still doesn't show up. I then changed the const to function and that did not do anything either

Comment: The function is correctly documented when I run the default jsdoc cli with no options? Please may you update the question showing a [mcve]?

Comment: The code works in isolation but combined with the other function, it doesn't appear in the html file. I will edit the post with the full function.

Comment: @YanatMengisha did the update make sense?